# Equivalent of loop in a loop in rxjs

Tags: rxjs

What is the equivalent of

```
array.forEach(element => {
  array.forEach(element2 => {
    //do something with element and element2
  });
});
```

in rxjs?

At the moment i 'solved' it like this

```
switchMap(array => from(array).pipe(
  tap(element => {
    array.forEach(element2 => {
      //do something with element and element2
    })
  })
)
```

or

```
let globalArray = [...someObjects];

of(globalArray).pipe(
  mergeMap(array => array),
  tap(element => {
    globalArray.forEach(element2 => {
      //do something with element and element2
    })
  })
)
```

(in the real code `globalArray` is an array that is passed to the function)

but this didn't feel like the right way to do it in rxjs.

Comment: Your second example is a bit weird. The `array` variable from `mergeMap` is not in scope inside the `tap` function. And this `mergeMap` would only work if `array` is actually an observable of an array, which would require the subject to be an observable of an observable of an array.

Comment: you are right. The second example gots wrong when i simplified it for SO.

Comment: There's no equivalent because this has nothing to do with rxjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your questions, `mergeMap` is the operator you are looking for.

`mergeMap` requires, as its first parameter, a function which returns an ObservableInput. Array is an ObservableInput. When an Array is returned, `mergeMap` flattens the Array and emit each Item as a separate notification.

So the following code should do what you are looking for

```
of(arrayOfArraysOfNumbers)
.pipe(
  mergeMap(arrayOfArrays => arrayOfArrays),
  mergeMap(array => array)
)
.subscribe(console.log)
```

Here an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-6efuvj?devtoolsheight=60).

**UPDATE - SAME ARRAY LOOPED TWICE**

Of you have to loop the same array twice, you may look at something like this

```
function closureForArray(arrayOfElements: Array<any>) {
  return from(arrayOfElements).pipe(
    mergeMap(e1 => from(arrayOfElements).pipe(
      map(e2 => ({e1, e2}))
    ))
  )
}

of(arrayOfElements)
.pipe(
  switchMap(closureForArray),
  map(({e1, e2}) => // do something with e1 and e2)
)
```

The basic idea here is that the `closureForArray` function keeps `arrayOfElements` in scope and therefore can apply the `from` RxJS function twice, one to run the first loop and the other to run the second loop from within the first loop.

Here the [updated example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-wytxjw?devtoolsheight=60).

Comment: no thats not what i want. I want the same array looped twice and combine the elements. Like a matrix where on the diagonal the element hits itself. In my initial question `array` is the same array.